# Gradle error - expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway

Tags: compiler-errors, gradle, line, newline, expected-exception

I'm getting this error while running one Gradle task.

```
:46:52 * Where:
14:46:52 Initialization script '/production/builds/jenkins_slave01/gradle-1.6/init.d/extra1.common-thids.gradle' line: 119
14:46:52 
14:46:52 * What went wrong:
14:46:52 Could not compile initialization script '/production/builds/jenkins_slave01/gradle-1.6/init.d/extra1.common-thids.gradle'.
14:46:52 > startup failed:
14:46:52   initialization script '/production/builds/jenkins_slave01/gradle-1.6/init.d/extra1.common-thids.gradle': 119: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 119, column 57.
14:46:52      ("$buildDir/reports/tests/IT")
14:46:52                                    ^
14:46:52   
14:46:52   1 error
14:46:52 
14:46:52 
14:46:52 * Try:
14:46:52 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
14:46:52 
14:46:53 BUILD FAILED
```

Gradle code behind this task is:

```
   task integrationTest( type: Test) {
     /Alway run tests
     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
     ignoreFailuers = true

     testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
     classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

     testReportDir  = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/IT")
     testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/IT")

     // This section in integrationTest and acceptanceTest task is actually not required here as jacocoagent.jar will be passed to Tomcat JVM instance than Gradle's instance.
     // Following Jacoco section is required only in Jenkins
     // But a developer can uncomment them if they want this feature to work for their
     // Desktop local Gradle builds.

     // This section in integrationTest and acceptanceTest task is actually not required here as jacocoagent.jar will be passed to Tomcat JVM instance than Gradle's instance.
     //jacoco {
       //The following vars works ONLY with 1.6 of Gradle
       //destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec")
       //classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps") --- commenting this out so we don't get errors - MG
       //
       //Following vars works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
       //destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
       //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")
     //}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh oh.. I scratched my head a lot for a misplaced **"** or **'** or **}** or **{** or **brackets** but forgot one simple thing.

```
/Alway run tests
```

This above COMMENT line should have been like the following i.e. I was missing a **/**.

```
//Alway run tests
```